# App monitor location on background service

Tags: android, background, gps

I would like to make an app that always works in the background (from boot up), which sends GPS coordinates to a server. This app should ALWAYS be active and should never close.
Should I use the services? I would like to use UDP sockets to send coordinates but I accept alternatives. I would also like to avoid using the google API.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: use jobintentservice with alarm with broadcastreciever on specific time for example each 5mins send coordinates to your server

Comment: Cool! Could You explain it bettere to me? Sorry I'm newbie in android LoL

Comment: hold on i will post answer

Comment: @J Doe check my answer hope it help you if fit your needs please mark it as correct  and vote up

Answer (score 1):

If your app need to run in the background , you need Service and you need to make it a foreground service which means you need to show a notification to the user as long as your application is running.

To open app on device boot, from Android O, its not allowed. You will get an IllegalStateException.
The main reason for this is to prevent exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Its not good to keep running an app in the background and its especially bad to keep tracking users GPS coordinates and send it to the server.
Because it will drain the battery very soon.

However it is possible to keep a foreground service running which can take the GPS coordinates and send it to the server. But for that user has to open your App first.

Please refer to
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services

Other alternative is to use JobIntentService which will schedule your tasks in smart ways to avoid draining users battery and data.

Regarding UDP sockets , it depends on your backend.

Comment: Mmmm okay, but for example: Whatsapp is always working on background because is always listening to new messages and I NEVER saw a notification by whatsapp.. how whatsapp do that?

Comment: Apps like whatsapp uses GCM , google cloud messaging.
Instead of apps running in the background and listening to new messages, whatsapp server directly pushes the messages to the users device.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: So what if I make an app on my server which send an UDP message to the smartphone telling him to send coordinates? Could that be better?